# Error in migration of stored procedure from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure that migrates from SQL Server to PostgreSQL this is the procedure:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public."ProcesarInformacionSP"(IN "ProcesoGeneral" character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$  
BEGIN   
    
if("ProcesoGeneral" = 'R')  
then    
    
    SELECT distinct "ProcesoInterno"
    FROM "ProcesarInformacion"
    where "ProcesoGeneral"= "ProcesoGeneral";
else    
    
    SELECT "ProcesoInterno"
    FROM public."ProcesarInformacion"
    where "ProcesoGeneral"= "ProcesoGeneral"
    order by "Orden";
end if; 
END;    
$procedure$
;
```

But when I try to run it I get this error:

> SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: reference to column "ProcesoGeneral" is ambiguous
> Detail: Could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you want your solution in... and specify what your actual requirements are rather than "I need to translate this" - there might not be a direct translation, but if we understand your requirements a solution can be found.

Comment: Read [Variable substitution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST).

Comment: If you want to return a result you need to use a function, not a procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the parameter to the procedure has the same name as a column in the table. Qualifying the identifiers in the queries resolves the issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public."ProcesarInformacionSP" (IN "ProcesoGeneral" character varying)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
BEGIN
    IF ("ProcesoGeneral" = 'R') THEN
        SELECT DISTINCT
            "ProcesoInterno"
        FROM
            "ProcesarInformacion"
        WHERE
            "ProcesarInformacion"."ProcesoGeneral" = "ProcesarInformacionSP"."ProcesoGeneral";
    ELSE
        SELECT
            "ProcesoInterno"
        FROM
            public."ProcesarInformacion"
        WHERE
            "ProcesarInformacion"."ProcesoGeneral" = "ProcesarInformacionSP"."ProcesoGeneral"
        ORDER BY
            "Orden";
    END IF;
END;
$procedure$;
```

In the above, I've only qualified the affected identifiers to clearly demonstrate what needed to change; however, I generally qualify column and parameter names in queries. Doing so avoids potential conflicts between names and makes the values' sources easily identifiable. Both of these can be important considerations, especially when queries involve joins between many tables.

Note: I've only addressed the issues related to unqualified identifiers. I haven't addressed any other issues that might be present, such as a lack of a return value (either add an OUT parameter, or change the procedure to a function).